# Strange Android Studio behavior

Tags: android, imageview, glsurfaceview

I'm developing app for image editing and for some reasons something go wrong. App started to throw error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ekalips/com.example.ekalips.EditorActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.opengl.GLSurfaceView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.opengl.GLSurfaceView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
    at com.example.ekalips.EditorActivity.onCreate(EditorActivity.java:31)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
```

But I'm not really trying to convert. Here's activity code:

```
public class EditorActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{
    private boolean isFullScreen = false;
    PhotoViewAttacher attacher;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Context context;

    private GLSurfaceView mEffectView;
    private int[] mTextures = new int[2];
    private EffectContext mEffectContext;
    private Effect mEffect;
    private TextureRenderer mTexRenderer = new TextureRenderer();
    private int mImageWidth;
    private int mImageHeight;
    private boolean mInitialized = false;
    int mCurrentEffect;
    Uri uri;
    Filter[] filterColl = new Filter[24];
    public void setCurrentEffect(int effect) {
        mCurrentEffect = effect;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editor);
        context = this;

        uri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("urilol"));
        mEffectView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.effectsview);
        mEffectView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mEffectView.setRenderer(this);
        mEffectView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
        mCurrentEffect = R.id.none;

        final ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menuBtn);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPopup(v);
            }
        });

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        filterColl[0] = new Filter(0,"None");
        filterColl[1] =new Filter(1,"Autofix");
        filterColl[2] =new Filter(2,"Min/Max Color Intensity");
        filterColl[3] =new Filter(3,"Brightness");
        filterColl[4] =new Filter(4,"Contrast");
        filterColl[5] =new Filter(5,"Cross Process");
        filterColl[6] =new Filter(6,"Documentary");
        filterColl[7] =new Filter(7,"Duo Tone");
        filterColl[8] =new Filter(8,"Fill Light");
        filterColl[9] =new Filter(9,"Fish Eye");
        filterColl[10] =new Filter(10,"Flip Vertical");
        filterColl[11] =new Filter(11,"Flip Horizontal");
        filterColl[12] =new Filter(12,"Grain");
        filterColl[13] =new Filter(13,"Grayscale");
        filterColl[14] =new Filter(14,"Lomoish");
        filterColl[15] =new Filter(15,"Negative");
        filterColl[16] =new Filter(16,"Posterize");
        filterColl[17] =new Filter(17,"Rotate");
        filterColl[18] =new Filter(18,"Saturate");
        filterColl[19] =new Filter(19,"Sepia");
        filterColl[20] =new Filter(20,"Sharpen");
        filterColl[21] =new Filter(21,"Temperature");
        filterColl[22] =new Filter(22,"Tint");
        filterColl[23] =new Filter(23,"Vignette");

        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(filterColl);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
                        Log.d("lele",textView.getText().toString() + "text");
                          mEffectView.requestRender();
                    }
                })
        );


    }


    public void showPopup(View v) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.edit_menu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                setCurrentEffect(item.getItemId());
                mEffectView.requestRender();
                return true;
            }
        });
        popup.show();
    }

    private void loadTextures() {
        // Generate textures
        GLES20.glGenTextures(2, mTextures, 0);

        // Load input bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), uri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mImageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        mImageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        mTexRenderer.updateTextureSize(mImageWidth, mImageHeight);

        // Upload to texture
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[0]);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        // Set texture parameters
        GLToolbox.initTexParams();
    }

    private void initEffect() {
        EffectFactory effectFactory = mEffectContext.getFactory();
        if (mEffect != null) {
            mEffect.release();
        }
        /**
         * Initialize the correct effect based on the selected menu/action item
         */
        switch (mCurrentEffect) {

            case R.id.none:
                break;

            case R.id.autofix:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_AUTOFIX);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", 0.5f);
                break;

            case R.id.bw:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_BLACKWHITE);
                mEffect.setParameter("black", .1f);
                mEffect.setParameter("white", .7f);
                break;

            case R.id.brightness:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_BRIGHTNESS);
                mEffect.setParameter("brightness", 2.0f);
                break;

            case R.id.contrast:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_CONTRAST);
                mEffect.setParameter("contrast", 1.4f);
                break;

            case R.id.crossprocess:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_CROSSPROCESS);
                break;

            case R.id.documentary:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_DOCUMENTARY);
                break;

            case R.id.duotone:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_DUOTONE);
                mEffect.setParameter("first_color", Color.YELLOW);
                mEffect.setParameter("second_color", Color.DKGRAY);
                break;

            case R.id.filllight:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_FILLLIGHT);
                mEffect.setParameter("strength", .8f);
                break;

            case R.id.fisheye:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_FISHEYE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .5f);
                break;

            case R.id.flipvert:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_FLIP);
                mEffect.setParameter("vertical", true);
                break;

            case R.id.fliphor:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_FLIP);
                mEffect.setParameter("horizontal", true);
                break;

            case R.id.grain:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_GRAIN);
                mEffect.setParameter("strength", 1.0f);
                break;

            case R.id.grayscale:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_GRAYSCALE);
                break;

            case R.id.lomoish:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_LOMOISH);
                break;

            case R.id.negative:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);
                break;

            case R.id.posterize:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_POSTERIZE);
                break;

            case R.id.rotate:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_ROTATE);
                mEffect.setParameter("angle", 180);
                break;

            case R.id.saturate:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_SATURATE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .5f);
                break;

            case R.id.sepia:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_SEPIA);
                break;

            case R.id.sharpen:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_SHARPEN);
                break;

            case R.id.temperature:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_TEMPERATURE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .9f);
                break;

            case R.id.tint:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_TINT);
                mEffect.setParameter("tint", Color.MAGENTA);
                break;

            case R.id.vignette:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(
                        EffectFactory.EFFECT_VIGNETTE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .5f);
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }
    }
    private void applyEffect() {
        mEffect.apply(mTextures[0], mImageWidth, mImageHeight, mTextures[1]);
    }

    private void renderResult() {
        if (mCurrentEffect != R.id.none) {
            // if no effect is chosen, just render the original bitmap
            mTexRenderer.renderTexture(mTextures[1]);
        }
        else {
            // render the result of applyEffect()
            mTexRenderer.renderTexture(mTextures[0]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        if (mTexRenderer != null) {
            mTexRenderer.updateViewSize(width, height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        if (!mInitialized) {
            //Only need to do this once
            mEffectContext = EffectContext.createWithCurrentGlContext();
            mTexRenderer.init();
            loadTextures();
            mInitialized = true;
        }
        if (mCurrentEffect != R.id.none) {
            //if an effect is chosen initialize it and apply it to the texture
            initEffect();
            applyEffect();
        }
        renderResult();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        setCurrentEffect(item.getItemId());
        mEffectView.requestRender();
        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is activity xml code:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.djqrj.allah.EditorActivity">
        <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/effectsview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/menuBtn"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:background="#B3000000"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/menuBtn"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to Build - Clean/Rebuild Project,deleting R.class file but it didn't help.

Also before this error I had another one - when I tried to add  app rejected to start because `NullPointerException` in `onClickListener` (java code wasn't changed, but error appeared when adding ).

Thanks for help.

Comment: Looks like you are casting GLSurfaceView to an ImageView. Not an Android Studio problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states that the code running on your device (or emulator), on line 31 of EditorActivity.java in the `onCreate()` method, you are trying to cast to ImageView but what you have is a GLSurfaceView.

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.opengl.GLSurfaceView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
> at com.example.ekalips.EditorActivity.onCreate(EditorActivity.java:31)
> ```

Since the code you posted doesn't have any references to ImageView my guess is that the code you are looking at is not the code you are running.  Clean, rebuild, and then be sure to install the newly built app on the device.  Make sure the installation of the new app doesn't fail leaving you with an old version running on the device.